# Blender 2.8+ Camera Tracking with variable Focal Length (zooming)?

Tags: camera, tracking

I've seen on a couple forums that camera tracking with variable focal length used to be planned for blender all the way back in 2013 (for example [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/does-motion-tracking-work-with-optical-zoom/573821/4)).  Though all links I've found linking to the Todo ticket are broken.

Is track camera motion while also tracking changes in focal length still a planned feature?  In addition, being that this has been talked about since 2013 why hasn't it been added yet?

Comment: As far as I know tracking shots with zoom not possible in blender. As to why? I'm sure is not a trivial thing to do,  but only the developers can tell you about their priorities. you might want to ask them directly https://devtalk.blender.org/.  This site is not associated the development of blender.

Comment: Thank you @susu for the link!  I was looking for some blender forum like that, but couldn't find it.  I decided to post this question there: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-camera-tracking-with-variable-focal-length-zooming/14912